# AG-Grid React no longer working with custom css

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm still new to ReactJS and using AG-Grid. My react app uses simple ag-grids with a simple css file for custom colors. Last week, this was working fine and had the colors I wanted. Today, all of the grids have rendered with the base theme (ag-theme-balham) and is no longer using my custom theme. I have no idea why its suddenly stopped working, I haven't made any changes since I was last on this project. Below are images of the grid last week, and this week, as well as the code that was working and seems to no longer.

[Grid last week with working custom styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K15w4.png)
[Grid today, with basic Balham theme and no custom styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tQmD.png)

```
ag-theme-balham.css

.ag-theme-balham{
    --ag-borders:none;
    --ag-data-color: #152A2E;
    --ag-row-border-style: none;
    --ag-row-hover-color: #5a676e5f;
    --ag-background-color: #90d6ca7f;
    --ag-header-foreground-color: #152A2E;
    --ag-header-background-color: #90D6CA;
    --ag-odd-row-background-color: #90d6ca9f;
    --ag-selected-row-background-color: #90D6CA;
    --ag-font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

GroupsTable.js

import { useState, useRef, useMemo, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

import '../../css/GridStyles.css'
import '../../css/ag-theme-balham.css'
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

function GroupsTable(props) {
    const gridRef = useRef();
    const containerStyle = useMemo(() => ({
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }), []);

    const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({
        width: props.width ?? 500,
        height: props.height ?? 762
    }), [props])
    const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null);

    const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => ({
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true
    }), []);

    const columnDefs = [
        {
            field: 'name',
            width: 150,
            minWidth: 150,
            maxWidth: 250
        }, {
            field: 'description',
            width: 300,
            minWidth: 150,
            maxWidth: 1000
        }
    ];

    const gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        defaultColDef: defaultColDef,
        rowSelection: props.selection ?? 'single',
        animateRows: true,
        suppressHorizontalScroll: true,
        suppressRowClickSelection: false
    }

    const sizeToFit = useCallback(() => {
        gridRef.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }, []);

    function gridReadyHandler(params) {
        setGridApi(params.api);
        sizeToFit();
    }

    return (
        <div style={containerStyle}>
            <div className='ag-theme-balham' style={gridStyle}>
                <AgGridReact
                    ref={gridRef}
                    rowData={filteredGroups}
                    gridOptions={gridOptions}
                    onGridReady={gridReadyHandler}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GroupsTable;
```

I've looked at recent changelogs for ag-grid-community but can't find anything that would have caused issues, I'm using ag-grid version 29. I've tried rewriting and even changing my custom file and style names to "ag-theme-custom" and directly adding that to className={}. Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this or how I can get any kind of customization to work again?

```
package.json

"dependencies": {
    "ag-grid-community": "^29.2.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^29.2.0",
  }
```